# An issue with implementing Push Notification for ios using Rocket Chat React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, rocket.chat

I am trying to implement Push Notification with the ios app, as I tested the .pem file its ok and I am able to send push notification but as I am unable to get the push notification from rocket chat app. In fact, I don’t find any guide on how to activate push notification with rocket chat.

Here are the steps I followed.

Here are my rocket chat push settings :[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j38u.png)

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01FlD.png)

by following these instructions:

https://github.com/raix/push/blob/v3.x/docs/IOS.md

Let me know where i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think  that you need to disable gateway. From Rocket.Chat documentation:

```
    Go to “Administration”, then “Push”
    Set the Enable Gateway to False, then you will use your own
    Rocket.Chat as gateway instead of the https://rocket.chat server
    Restart server

 Now you should be able to Send a test message. 
Make sure that you have logged in to  the server once, and then closed 
the app. You should see a test notification after you pressed the 
send button.
```